# Fetch request doens't return the requested data

Tags: javascript, xml, fetch, es6-promise

I'm trying to get XML data with a fetch() request and the appropriate header.
The request succeeds but the reponse is empty. The weird part is that the browsers networking tab in the debugger gives me a 200 OK and has the requested Response payload but I can't seem to get this data even though it's present. Any clues as to why?

[Snapshot of the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGUs1.png)

```js
data = {
            get:(url)=>{
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    let auth = new Headers({
                        "username":key.user,
                        "password":key.password,
                        "Accept":"application/xml"                 
                    })
                    
                    fetch(url,{
                        method:"get",
                        mode:"no-cors",
                        headers: auth,
                        credentials:"include"
                    })
                    .then(response => console.log(response))
                    //empty response
                })
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a cross-origin request but you said `mode:"no-cors",`.

`mode:"no-cors",` means "If I need permission to do something cross-origin, then don't ask for it, and don't throw an error".

> [no-cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) — Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET or POST, and the headers from being anything other than simple headers. If any ServiceWorkers intercept these requests, they may not add or override any headers except for those that are simple headers. In addition, JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response. This ensures that ServiceWorkers do not affect the semantics of the Web and prevents security and privacy issues arising from leaking data across domains.

Since you **need** permission to read data from a cross-origin request, it is failing silently (because you explicitly told it to do so).

Use `mode: "cors"`.